# How do I put two views at the same position using "auto layout visual format"?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I want to put two views at the same position using "auto layout visual format" in Swift, how do I do that in an elegant way?

I succeeded using NSLayoutConstraint, but I hope I can still find an elegant way using visual format.

My code using NSLayoutConstraint:

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: greenView, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: redView, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).active = true
NSLayoutConstraint(item: greenView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: redView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).active = true
NSLayoutConstraint(item: greenView, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: redView, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).active = true
NSLayoutConstraint(item: greenView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: redView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).active = true
```

Comment: By reading the docs? This is not a "do my work for me" site. Take a stab at doing it yourself, and if you can't get it working, post your code here and we'll help you debug it.

Comment: @DuncanC I don't think it's an inappropriate question. I've been working on it. I am still working on it right now. I didn't see any similar question posted on SO, so I posted it. And I thought it's a simple, clear enough question that I don't need to post my wrong code. I will search more and post mine later.

Answer (score 7):

I would echo [what vacawama said in his excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38410663/5086440) about using layout anchors.  It's probably as clear and elegant as you get with the native API, but please note that it requires iOS 9 and later.

For the purpose of code organization, I'd like to suggest instead of looking for terser code, organize your code into methods and/or extensions, for example:

```
extension UIView {

    func constraintsAligningAllEdges(toView view2: UIView) -> [NSLayoutConstraint] {

        return [ topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view2.topAnchor),
                 bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view2.bottomAnchor),
                 leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view2.leadingAnchor),
                 trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view2.trailingAnchor) ]
    }
}
```

Using it would look like this:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(greenView.constraintsAligningAllEdges(toView: redView))
```

...or perhaps make that a class function extension for NSLayoutConstraint.

On the topic of *Visual Format Language*, [vacawama](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38410663/5086440) also brought up a very interesting use of the layout options.  Here's another possible way of achieving the same goal:

```
let views = ["greenView" : greenView, "redView" : redView]

NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(
    NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[greenView]-(0@1)-[redView]", options: [.AlignAllTop, .AlignAllBottom], metrics: nil, views: views) +
    NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[greenView]-(0@1)-[redView]", options: [.AlignAllLeading, .AlignAllTrailing], metrics: nil, views: views)
)
```

What I've done here is instead of introducing extra views, I've introduced two extraneous constraints, one between green bottom & red top, another one between green trailing & top leading.  They both have the lowest priority of `1` however, so as you would normally have other constraints deciding the size/position of either view, they should cause no harm.

Is this somewhat more elegant?  I don't know, but personally I think layout anchors make more sense to me, and third-party frameworks like SnapKit are also fine options.

Comment: Excellent.  Great answer.

Comment: This gave me another idea.  You could use `constraints.filter {$0.priority != 1}` to remove those extra constraints entirely before activating them.

Comment: That's is amazing guys!

This would be

```
        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(
            NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[greenView]-(0@1)-[redView]", options: [.AlignAllTop, .AlignAllBottom], metrics: nil, views: views).filter {$0.priority != 1} +
            NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[greenView]-(0@1)-[redView]", options: [.AlignAllLeading, .AlignAllTrailing], metrics: nil, views: views).filter {$0.priority != 1}
        )
```

Comment: Or add the two together sets of constraints together and then filter that.  There's nothing wrong with storing intermediate values with `let`.  It makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 3):

The *Visual Format Language* can't be used for every possible case.  I believe aligning the two views to each other is such a case.

I would suggest you use layout anchors instead, like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let redView = UIView()
    redView.backgroundColor = .redColor()
    redView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    view.addSubview(redView)

    let greenView = UIView()
    greenView.backgroundColor = .greenColor()
    greenView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    view.addSubview(greenView)

    let redHoriz = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-20-[redView]-20-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["redView": redView])
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(redHoriz)

    let redVert = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-50-[redView]-50-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["redView": redView])
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(redVert)

    // Set greenView to occupy same space as the redView
    greenView.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(redView.leftAnchor).active = true
    greenView.rightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(redView.rightAnchor).active = true
    greenView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(redView.topAnchor).active = true
    greenView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(redView.bottomAnchor).active = true
}
```

---

The *Visual Format Language* allows you to align *parts* of views.  For instance, you can align the tops of bottoms of two views by passing `[.AlignAllTop, .AlignAllBottom]` as the `options` argument of `constraintsWithFormat`.  But,  you can only align values that are perpendicular to the direction of the *visual format*.  So, if you are specifying a horizontal layout, then you can align the *tops* and *bottoms* of the views.  If you are specifying a vertical layout, then you can align the *lefts* and *rights*.

You can align two views by introducing two additional views.  In the example below, the blue view picks up the *top* and *bottom* alignment of the red view, and the yellow view picks up the *left* and *right* alignment of the red view.  Then the green view gets aligned to the *top* and *bottom* of the blue view and the *left* and *right* of the yellow view, thus it is aligned to the red view.

Finally, hiding the blue and yellow views leaves you with the setup you desire.

[image: VFL example]

```
    let redView = UIView()
    redView.backgroundColor = .redColor()
    redView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    view.addSubview(redView)

    let greenView = UIView()
    greenView.backgroundColor = .greenColor()
    greenView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    view.addSubview(greenView)

    let blueView = UIView()
    blueView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    blueView.backgroundColor = .blueColor()
    blueView.hidden = true

    view.addSubview(blueView)

    let yellowView = UIView()
    yellowView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    yellowView.backgroundColor = .yellowColor()
    yellowView.hidden = true

    view.addSubview(yellowView)

    let redHoriz = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-80-[redView]-80-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["redView": redView])
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(redHoriz)

    let redVert = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-80-[redView]-80-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["redView": redView])
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(redVert)

    let blueHorizVert = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[redView][blueView]|", options: [.AlignAllTop, .AlignAllBottom], metrics: nil, views: ["redView": redView, "blueView": blueView])
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(blueHorizVert)

    let yellowHorizVert = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[redView][yellowView]|", options: [.AlignAllLeft, .AlignAllRight], metrics: nil, views: ["redView": redView, "yellowView": yellowView])
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(yellowHorizVert)

    let greenTopBottom = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[greenView][blueView]|", options: [.AlignAllTop, .AlignAllBottom], metrics: nil, views: ["greenView": greenView, "blueView": blueView])
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(greenTopBottom)

    let greenLeftRight = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[greenView][yellowView]|", options: [.AlignAllLeft, .AlignAllRight], metrics: nil, views: ["greenView": greenView, "yellowView": yellowView])
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(greenLeftRight)
```

So you *can* do it with VFL, but it isn't elegant.  I would suggest you stick with using anchors.

Comment: Thank you for providing the answer. I didn't know how to use alignAnchor.
I succeeded with NSLayoutConstraint. But I hope I can still find an elegant way using auto layout visual format.

Comment: Just only NSConstraint manually. I added my code in the question. Help me keep this question open please :p

Comment: I figured out a way to do it with VFL, but it *isn't elegant*.